# Critical Points of a function for special cases

Tags: derivatives

I understand that critical point is any point on a graph where f'(c) = 0. but when I have a function like f(x) = $|X|$, is there a critical point at x = 0 if the point is not differentiable?

Also, can someone give me any example of when x = c is the location of a local extremum, then tangent line of f at x = c does not exist?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Observe that the function admits the local extremum aither at the point $c$ with $f'(c)=0$ (a critical point) or an the point, where the derivative does not exist. The $f(x)=|x|$ function has the minimum at the point of non-differentiabliity. It such point there is no tangent line. Any function with a point of non-differentiability could serve as an example for your 2nd question.